# No ambient occlusion in render output with eevee, whether it is displayed in the rendering preview. What is the reason and how to solve this?

Tags: rendering, ambient-occlusion

As you see in the image, there is no ambient occlusion in the rendering output, whether it was displayed in the rendering preview. What is wrong in my settings? [image: No ambient occlusion in render output.]

---

I don see any AO in the AO pass [image: AO pass]

It seems that I destroying something using the following script.
Moreover, I have the feeling that blender uses for the rendering preview different rendering settings as with F12 or in the script.

````
import os
import bpy
import csv
from math import radians
import math

dims=[['BBX','BBY','BBZ']]
mdl_fpath="C:\\blender_test_folder\\7406527\\7406527.stl"
output_fpath="C:\\blender_test_folder\\7406527"


#bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")
#bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True)
print('TEST')

def normtrans_to_center(mdl):
    #mdl = bpy.context.object
    mdl_dims = [mdl.dimensions[0],mdl.dimensions[1],mdl.dimensions[2]]
    max_dim = max(mdl_dims)
    mdl.scale[0]=2/max_dim
    mdl.scale[1]=2/max_dim
    mdl.scale[2]=2/max_dim
    #bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY') with attribute center = 'BOUNDS' better results.
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='BOUNDS')
    mdl.location=[0,0,0]
    return mdl_dims



bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.engine='BLENDER_EEVEE'
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.resolution_percentage=100
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].eevee.use_gtao = True
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].eevee.gtao_distance=50
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].eevee.gtao_factor=30


#try:
   # bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].cycles.device='GPU'
#except:
#    pass

res = 512
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = res
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = res
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.tile_x = res/2
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.tile_y = res

bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.image_settings.file_format = 'JPEG'
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.image_settings.color_mode = 'BW'
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.compression = 0

file = os.path.join(output_fpath, 'test_1')
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = file


#bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD',location=(0.0,0.0,5.0), rotation=(0, 0, 0))
#bpy.context.object.data.lens=50
#bpy.context.object.data.clip_end = 300
#bpy.context.object.data.clip_start = 0.001

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=mdl_fpath,axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z', filter_glob="*.stl", files=[], directory="", global_scale=1, use_scene_unit=False, use_facet_normal=False)
mdl_name = bpy.context.object.name
mdl_object = bpy.context.object
print(mdl_object.type)
print(mdl_name)
dims.append(normtrans_to_center(bpy.context.object))
bpy.context.object.location=[0,0,0]


for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'CAMERA':
        #bpy.context.space_data.show_only_render = True
        bpy.context.scene.camera = obj
        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False,write_still=True)
```
````

Comment: Take a look at "view layer properties" -> Passes. Do you have AO enabled as a separate pass?

Comment: Hallo harriger Troll, thank's for your reply. As you aspected AO was not set under Passes. But unfortunatelly, there is still no ambient occlusion in the rendering output also with AO set under Passes. (Blender version 2.82)

Comment: Actually, it is supposed to show up in your completed rendering, when it is NOT set to be rendered as a separate pass.
But when you check the "pass"-option - can you see the pass in your render result window?

Comment: In my render result window, I can see under pass: Combined, Depth and AO.

Comment: And how does the AO pass look?

Comment: I have the same question.